# Read the page number while scraping a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read and put in a variable only the page number from an URL link.. which I scraped from a website. below is the print output of the variable which I scraped from the website

```
<li><a href="https://bp.portwallet.com/report/topUp?source=gp_web&amp;allSearch=&amp;amountFrom=1&amp;amountTo=50000&amp;startdate=2018-10-03&amp;enddate=2018-10-03&amp;topUpSearch=topUpSearch&amp;status=1&amp;rType=Prepaid&amp;per_page=46">Last ›</a></li>
```

I need to put the per_page= value into a variable..

I tried to scrape only the number but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = '''<li><a href="https://bp.portwallet.com/report/topUp?source=gp_web&amp;allSearch=&amp;amountFrom=1&amp;amountTo=50000&amp;startdate=2018-10-03&amp;enddate=2018-10-03&amp;topUpSearch=topUpSearch&amp;status=1&amp;rType=Prepaid&amp;per_page=46">Last ›</a></li>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
x = soup.select('a')
per_page = (x[0]['href']).split('per_page=')[-1]
print('per_page:', per_page)
```

Output:

```
per_page: 46
```